# presentModalViewController not taking full screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, presentmodalviewcontroller

Landscape only app.  On my main window xib, I've got a UIView.  I'm loading a UIScrollview programatically into that UIView which works just fine.  On that scrollview, I've got a button that brings up a "detail" screen (a separate view controller), via a presentModalViewController call:

```
    LearnITViewController *learnit = [[LearnITViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LearnITViewController" bundle:nil];
self.learnitView = learnit;
[self presentModalViewController:learnit animated:YES];    
[learnit release];
```

The action's being called but the modal view doesn't take up the whole screen when the scrollview is a subview.  Instead, it's popping into the parent scrollview and flipping the orientation, etc.  Not the desired behavior.

Any guidance on how to make the modal view full screen when the call is from scrollview which is a subview of a container UIView on the main xib?

Comment: post some code related to scrollview

Comment: This one makes trouble, i too have faced it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments.  Found a tip somewhere on overriding presentModalViewController and bubbling up in a loop until the main controller's reached (in my case, HomeViewController).  Worked like a champ.

```
- (void) presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)screen animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIResponder *responder = self;
    while (responder && ![responder isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]) {
        responder = [responder nextResponder];
    }
    [(UIViewController *)responder presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
}
```

I'm overriding in the .m file of the UIScrollview that contains the button that makes the call.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `subview`, rather than `presentModelViewController` as:

```
LearnITViewController *tempView = [[LearnITViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LearnITViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.learnITViewController = tempView;
[tempView release];
[self.view addSubview:mainMenuView.view];
```

And add This too

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);//or left
}
```

Comment: @7KV7: thanks for the edit, I thought we can go without of `self.` :)

Comment: Great, I'll give the superview a shot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
LearnITViewController *learnit = [[LearnITViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LearnITViewController" bundle:nil];
self.learnitView = learnit;
[self.learnitView setsetWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

or

```
self.learnitView.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:learnit animated:YES];    
[learnit release];
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `self` add `UIViewController` in `superview`.

```
LearnITViewController *learnit = [[LearnITViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LearnITViewController" bundle:nil];
self.learnitView = learnit;
[self.view.superview presentModalViewController:learnit animated:YES];    
[learnit release];
```

Comment: self.view.superview is UIView. - (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated is implemented on top of UIViewController